# адаптивный слой с текстом над изабражением

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Добрый день.

Делаю один их своих первых сайтов и никак не могу настроить текст который появляется над изображением.

С мобильного приложения он получается слишком мелким и нечитабельным:
Как можно это исправить? Спасибо.

[image: вид с телефона]

```html
<!-- Slide -->
<li data-transition="random">
  <!-- Main Image -->
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf76f.png" alt="casa-prefabricada-galicia" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" data-no-retina>
  <!-- Layers -->
  <div class="sfb tp-caption tp-resizeme text-white font-family-heading text-shadow text-center font-weight-700 letter-spacing-2px" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']" data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']"
    data-voffset="['-99','-99','-99','-99']" data-fontsize="['58','54','50','46']" data-lineheight="['68','64','60','56']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="o:0" data-transform_out="o:0"
    data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-mask_out="x:0;y:0;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-start="1500" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-responsive_offset="on">

    <div style="background:RGBA(240, 240, 240, 0.7); width:auto;height:auto; font-size:40px; padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;line-height: 1;">
      <p style="color:#2C2C2C;">Nuestro objetivo</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="sfb tp-caption tp-resizeme text-white text-shadow text-center" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']" data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['-14','-14','-14','-14']" data-fontsize="['16','16','16','16']"
    data-lineheight="['30','30','30','28']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="o:0" data-transform_out="o:0" data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-mask_out="x:0;y:0;s:inherit;e:inherit;"
    data-start="1800" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-responsive_offset="on" data-lasttriggerstate="reset">

    <div style="background:RGBA(240, 240, 240, 0.7); width:auto;height:auto; font-size:22px; padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;line-height: 1.4;">
      <p style="color:#2C2C2C;">es construir casas con la más alta calidad y acorde a todos sus gustos y necesidades.<br> Por esto nuestros clientes tienen la posibilidad de participar en todo el proceso de construcción
        <br>aportando todas sus ideas ya que lo importante es que su hogar sea tal como siempre lo ha soñado</p>
    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="sfb tp-caption" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']" data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['83','83','83','83']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap"
    data-transform_hover="o:1;rX:0;rY:0;rZ:0;z:0;s:300;e:Power1.easeInOut;" data-style_hover="c:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);bc:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);cursor:pointer;" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="o:0" data-transform_out="o:0" data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;s:inherit;e:inherit;"
    data-start="2100" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-actions='[{"event":"click","action":"scrollbelow","offset":"20px"}]' data-responsive="on">
    <a href="quienes-somos.html" class="wprt-button rounded-3px">MÁS INFORMACIÓN</a>
  </div>
</li>
<!-- End Slide -->`
```

Comment: А такая строчка  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` в `head`  у тебя присутствует?

Comment: да,  <!-- Mobile Specific Metas -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

Comment: увеличь шрифт на мобильном разрешении

Comment: да, лучше всего медизапросы попробовать (то есть когда разрешение будет меньше заданного вами, то этот ваш текст будет увеличиваться, опять же - насколько также указываете вы)